# How to Fetch Email Address From Facebook in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

i am NewBie with Facebook login in iOS for Facebook login i make one FbView and I write a code for Fetch email and Name of User then it was Give me User name as i want but Email Address are getting as Null Please Give me Solution for this.

Here my Code like as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.fbView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
self.fbView.delegate=self;
 if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
    || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended)
{
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"Email %@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
             NSLog(@"User Name %@",user.username);
         }
     }];
}
```

And also i write a method For fetch Email like as

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                        user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
NSLog(@"User Name %@",user.name);
NSLog(@"Email %@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
}
```

But it was Give me `NULL` Value Please Give me Solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your second method, try like this,

```
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
  NSString *userDetails = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user];
  NSString *fb_userEmail = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
}
```

`userDetails` will return you all the user details in a single string object.
`fb_userEmail` will return users email id.